# Setting up simple communication between a PostgreSL local database and a cloud database

Tags: postgresql, cloud

We set up a local PostgreSQL DB to capture data from our chemical process. Now, we would like to send that data up to a cloud DB. We would like the cloud to hold all the data the local has ever received and for the local DB to only keep the last 2 weeks of data it has received.

Specifics:

- Our DB is pretty simple. Only a table that is updated with a new row every 3 seconds from the unit.
- We are a scientific company so I was thinking about using Flask (bc python) to do this, but TBH I don't really know if that is the right direction or overkill
- We don't know which hosting service would be best to use for this kind of simplistic need.
- Local computer: Windows 7

Others:

- I can connect to it on our local network, cannot find a way to connect to the DB remotely.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to centralize data in order to run some data analytics, right? You are probably looking for a data warehouse solution such as Redshift: https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/